# modifying the contents of a PasteOperation in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to capture and modify the contents of a paste operation in my Flex 4 application. I am listening for the TextOperation.CHANGING event, pulling out the PasteOperation, and setting its textScrap property. Everything seems to be working, except that after I modify the textScrap, a newline character is added to the paste. I have created some sample code that illustrates the simplest version of the problem. I am not actually changing the copy, I am grabbing the existing textScrap's textFlow, creating a new TextScrap with it, and setting it on the PasteOperation.  I did this to rule out TextFlow creation as the problem:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
        import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;

        import flashx.textLayout.edit.TextScrap;
        import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
        import flashx.textLayout.operations.PasteOperation;
        import flashx.textLayout.tlf_internal;

        import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

        use namespace tlf_internal;

        protected function textArea_changingHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
        {
            if (event.operation is PasteOperation)
            {
                var pasteOp:PasteOperation = event.operation as PasteOperation;

                pasteOp.textScrap = new TextScrap(pasteOp.textScrap.textFlow);
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TextArea id="textArea" changing="textArea_changingHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Thanks in advance,

Gerry

Comment: I compiled your app w/the Flex 4.6 SDK and didn't see a problem, no line breaks inserted when I pasted into the text area.

Comment: Verified!  This behavior only happens in sdk 4.1. Thanks, I didn't even think to try that!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug that Adobe fixed in sdk 4.6.

As some additional information, replacing the pasteOp.textScrap line above with:

pasteOp.textScrap = pasteOp.textScrap.clone() used to throw a null pointer exception, and in 4.6 that works too now.

Also, this bug only appeared when the textarea / textinput was empty.  if there was something already in there, everything worked as expected.